# How can I mandate certain scopes at the Google OAuth screen?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth

I am trying to pre-select the scopes required for my application to work.

I can see that this is possible as when I attempt to log in on the Hive website, I'm not given the option to de-select scopes.

[Hive login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyJOK.png)

However on my application (which Google has now approved for production use), the scopes I need are not checked by default.

[My Apps OAuth Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svooa.png)

Does anyone know how I can do what Hive is doing?

I have not yet found any information online regarding how to do this. Most Stackoverflow posts I've seen say this is not possible, yet, I've found a website which shows it is possible

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you have little influence on whether the checkboxes [are checked by default or not](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/more-granular-google-account.html). The basic rules are that checkboxes are *not* checked unless:

- the user and application are in the same Google Cloud organization (domain-owned apps)
- the administrator of the user's domain has configured the app as "trusted" (trusted apps)
- the scope is one one the standard OIDC scopes (email, etc)

[This post](https://jpassing.com/2022/08/01/dealing-with-partial-consent-in-google-oauth-clients/) contains some more details.